# Passing and event handler outside class

Tags: c#, oop, event-handling

This question is concerned with programming, but also about my architecture if it needs changes.

Basically, I have the microsoft band functionality wrapped in a class, I have a method within the class that subscribes to accelerometer changes as follow:

```
_bandClient.SensorManager.Accelerometer.ReadingChanged += Accelerometer_ReadingChanged;
```

I want to be able to call a method (event handler) from outside the class, so I did this:

```
public async Task ToggleAccelerometer(EventHandler<BandSensorReadingEventArgs<IBandAccelerometerReading>> del)
        {
            if (!_sensorState[Sensor.Accelerometer])
            {
                _sensorState[Sensor.Accelerometer] = true;
                _bandClient.SensorManager.Accelerometer.ReadingChanged += del;
                await _bandClient.SensorManager.Accelerometer.StartReadingsAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                _sensorState[Sensor.Accelerometer] = false;
                await _bandClient.SensorManager.Accelerometer.StopReadingsAsync();
            }
        }
```

And parameter del is implemented as follows:

```
private void Accelerometer_ValuesChanged(object sender, BandSensorReadingEventArgs<IBandAccelerometerReading> e)
        {
            IBandAccelerometerReading accelerometer = e.SensorReading;
            Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            IBandAccelerometerReading accelerometer = e.SensorReading;
            AccelXBlock.Text = accelerometer.AccelerationX.ToString();
            AccelYBlock.Text = accelerometer.AccelerationY.ToString();
            AccelZBlock.Text = accelerometer.AccelerationZ.ToString();
        }).AsTask();
        }
```

This works as intended, my question is:

Should I change my program
    design (is what I'm trying to do a bad practice?), if so, then what's the better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be doing event bubbling in a wrapper class. You can see how it implements Publisher/Subscriber pattern using `event`. See below:

```
// Wrapper
public class BandManager
{
    // Callers will subscribe to this event
    public event EventHandler<BandSensorReadingEventArgs<IBandAccelerometerReading>> ReadingChanged;

    public async Task ToggleAccelerometer()
    {
        if (!_sensorState[Sensor.Accelerometer])
        {
            _sensorState[Sensor.Accelerometer] = true;
            _bandClient.SensorManager.Accelerometer.ReadingChanged += OnReadingChanged;
            await _bandClient.SensorManager.Accelerometer.StartReadingsAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            _sensorState[Sensor.Accelerometer] = false;
            await _bandClient.SensorManager.Accelerometer.StopReadingsAsync();
        }
    }

    private void OnReadingChanged(object sender, BandSensorReadingEventArgs<IBandAccelerometerReading> e)
    {
        var readingChangedHandler = ReadingChanged;

        if(readingChangedHandler != null)
        {
            ReadingChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}

// Client
public class MainClass
{
    public async void Test()
    {
        var bandManager = new BandManager();
        bandManager.ReadingChanged += BandManager_ReadingChanged;
        var whatever = await bandManager.ToggleAccelerometer();
    }

    // This is event handler for your wrapper class
    private void BandManager_ReadingChanged(object sender, BandSensorReadingEventArgs<IBandAccelerometerReading> e)
    {
        // use 'e' as you need
    }
}
```